# The difference between "npm run tsc" vs spawn('tsc')

Tags: node.js, npm, spawn, tsc

I want to have a script, which will compile .ts files in my multiple repos. I try to run compilation via `spawnSync('tsc file.ts')` but I end up with **tsc is not recognized as internal/external command**.
Compiling the same file with `npm run tsc file.ts` works fine. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

So while running `npm run tsc file.ts` additional binary is added and local typescript is used to execute the command. When running `spawn('tsc file.ts') a global installed typescript is needed, and when not found, throws eerror.